# Using stored procedures of another database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have some procedures in `database1` that are used to fill some tables using `INSERT` statements.

The tables I want to fill are in `database2`. How can I write a query with `EXEC procedures` in order to fill those tables?

I don't want to add stored procedures in the same database of the tables (`database2`)

This is one of the the stored procedures in db1

```
USE [database1]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AddSubject]
@SubjectCode nvarchar(20),
@Credits int,
@Hours int

AS

INSERT INTO [database2].[dbo].[Subject]
       ([Code]
       ,[Credits]
       ,[Hours])
 VALUES
       (@SubjectCode,
       @Credits,
       @Hours)

 Return @@Identity
```

And here is where I execute the stored procedure:

```
EXEC    @SubID = [database1].[dbo].[AddSubject] @SubjectCode='1234', @Credits=2, @Hours=50
```

And it gives me the error:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure AddSubject, Line 14
Invalid object name 'database2.dbo.Subject'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refer to SQL Server tables with a [four-part name](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1095/sql-server-four-part-naming/):

```
server.database.schema.table
```

For a different database you only need the last three parts:

```
insert  otherdb.dbo.yourtable 
        (col1, col2, ...) 
values  ('val1', 'val2', ...)
```

You can use this in a stored procedure to insert into a table in a different database.

Comment: The error message suggests that the table does not exist.  Are you sure there is a `database2` on the same server, that has a `Subject` table in the `dbo` schema?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! you can acess the database2 into database1 for doing this both database should one server

If your scheema is **dbo** then you can access as below:-

```
Insert into database1..table_name (col1,col2)
select value1,value2
```

If your Scheema is **other than dbo** then :-

```
Insert into database1.Scheema_name.table_name (col1,col2)
select value1,value2
```

Comment: Same code is working at My end. couple of thing i have done @subid has declared before executing this.